# How to create restricted developers login for my apple dev account?

Tags: ios

I have just hired someone to develop an app for me. I want to know if there is a way to give restricted access for my developer, so that he is not able to use my apple login to buy things on itunes...

Comment: You can an external dev in iTunes Connect.

Comment: add him as team member and give him required privilleges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From developer.apple.com log into the member center and go to People.

Click Invitations and send an invitation to your new developer at their own email address.

The process for the developer accepting the invitation has them create a new Apple ID or link it to their own existing Apple ID. You will never need to give them access to your Apple ID. Just ensure that their role is "Member."

Now this is still separate from iTunes Connect. If you later want him to be able to administer your apps, etc., you can add their account there.